I sent funds to my gnosis Safe address on the wrong chain (ZkSync -> Scroll)
I'm wondering if its possible to recover the funds by deterministically deploying to the same address. The safe help docs (https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover) suggest that I'm screwed because the safe was deployed on zkSync era... I'm not totally sure why that matters. I'm wondering if I can deploy using Create2 with the same bytecode and salt (from the same deploying address). I guess part of the problem here might be that its a proxy and therefore the implementation it points to won't be correct since the Safe factory isn't deployed on Scroll at all...? Any thoughts/tips here?

Unfortunately, as discussed here or here, this is still not possible.
Best, Louis

Ok thanks Louis. Fortunately wasn't too much!
